# Unable to access variable element

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

My environment is PowerShell Version 4, 32 bit in Sapien Powershell Studio 2016.

The problem is an element of an array is not displaying.

Here is my code:

```
#Reduce Absences to this employee & date 
$Absthis = $AbsenceInfo | where {
    $_.StartDate -ge $CompDate -and
    $_.EndDate -le $CompDate -and
    $_.PayRef -eq $WP1
}

'Absence This Day'
$Absthis

'Absence Raw'
$Absthis.Payref
$Absthis.AbsenceCat
$Absthis.AbsenceType
$Absthis.StartDate
$Absthis.EndDate
$Absthis.NumDays
$Absthis.NumHrs

'Absence Write-Host'
Write-Host $Absthis.Payref
Write-Host $Absthis.AbsenceCat
Write-Host $Absthis.AbsenceType
Write-Host $Absthis.StartDate
Write-Host $Absthis.EndDate
Write-Host $Absthis.NumDays
Write-Host $Absthis.NumHrs
```

And here is the output:

```
Absence This Day
Payref       : 181
AbsenceCat  : 2
AbsenceType : Unauthorised
StartDate    : 31/01/2017
EndDate      : 31/01/2017
NumDays      : 1.00
NumHrs       : 0.00

Absence Raw
181
31/01/2017
31/01/2017
1.00
0.00

Absence Write-Host
181


31/01/2017
1/01/2017
1.00
0.00
```

Any idea why `$Absthis.AbsenceCat` and `$Absthis.AbsenceType` won't output?

Comment: The two property names look funky. Verify that there aren't any funny characters in them.

Comment: Good spot Ansgar - Thanks. They do seem to be out of alignment with the other variables, so I'll go have a play with the source file and feedback.

Comment: You are absolutely spot on Ansgar, the XLS source file has column names for both these fields have at least 2 whitespace characters at the end.So a tip for anyone exporting custom reports from Sage Line 50 / Sage Payroll - make sure your column headers are trimmed.